# Characterization of supremum

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

Let $A\subset(0,\infty)$ non empty. Show that $u=\sup A$ iff:

i) $\forall x \in A \quad x \leq u$

ii) $\forall d>1 \quad \exists a \in A: \frac{u}{d}<a$

One implication:

If $u=\sup A$, then we have i) from the definition. Let $d>1$, since $u>0$ we have $\frac{u}{d}<u$ and from another characterization of the supremum there exist $a\in A$ such that: $$u-u+\frac{u}{d}=\frac{u}{d}<a$$ since $u-\frac{u}{d}$ is positive.

For the other side, we have that $u$ is an upper bound from i), but I have not been able to show that is the least upper bound, not even using the previous characterization.

Comment: It might be helpful to state what is the def of supremum you are using.

Comment: The supremum is the least upper bound.

Comment: Hint: If $u$ were not the least upper bound, there would be an upper bound below it. Can you then find a $d>1$ that violates (ii)?

Comment: @celtschk Yes, $d=u/k$ with $k$ an upper bound below $u$. Thanks! :)

Comment: You're welcome.